# After sending mail I am not getting the correct output

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need help with `Send-MailMessage` using PowerShell.
The issue is that I am able to send mail through the cmdlet but after sending I want to check whether the mail is successfully delivered or not. So I am using an `if`/`else` statement for that. After running the script I am receiving mail in my inbox but PowerShell `Write-Host` is showing:

> Mail delivery failed... Try Again

Below is the code for reference:

```bsh
$Status = Send-MailMessage -To $to -From $from -Bcc $bcc -Credential 'xxx@gmail.com' -Subject $subject -Body $Body -Attachments $attachment -SmtpServer $server -Port 587 -UseSsl
if ($Status -eq "true" -or $Status -eq "True" -or $Status -eq 0 -or $Status -eq 1) {
    Write-Host "Mail sent...."
} else {
    Write-Host "Mail delivery failed... Try Again"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-3.0):

> ### Outputs
>
> **None**
>
> This cmdlet does not generate any output.

The cmdlet does not generate output, so `$Status` is empty, which equals neither "true" nor "True" nor 0 nor 1, so your comparisons always evaluate to false.

`Send-MailMessage` will throw an error when it is unable to submit the message, which you could handle like this:

```bsh
try {
    Send-MailMessage ...
    Write-Host "Mail sent...."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Mail delivery failed... Try Again"
}
```

---

As a side note, you can only verify whether the mail is successfully submitted (i.e. whether the mail server you specified accepted it for delivery). E-mail is a store-and-forward architecture, meaning that one hop accepting mail for delivery says nothing about whether or not the mail has reached the final recipient(s). E-mail uses so-called [bounce messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) for communicating delivery status back to the sender.

Comment: Hi Ansgar.. That worked for me. I have one more question for you.. I am executing one batch file (which executes 2 scripts: First one gathers information, Second one take the information and send email to respective person, but in second script everytime i have to enter my credential for sending mail).. Is there any way ?? to avoid this ??

Comment: @Vijay Currently the parameter `-Credential` is passed only the username without the password. Try passing a [`PSCredential` object](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/).